# Angular 4 Nuget Package

Tags: angular, nuget, nuget-package

I am looking to try out the new Angular release (4.1.x), however the Angular package on Nuget states that this is version 1.6.x - which was released in April coinciding with when Angular 4 was released. Does anybody know if this is the package I'm looking for if I wanted to work with the latest release of Angular 4?

Comment: 1.6 version of angular on nuget is angularJS, not angular (>2). There's no angular package on nuget (at least I found none, if there's some packages, they have to be hidden somewhere).

Comment: Thanks that's great - if you want to pop that in as the answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: I added more details in an answer format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular's package present on Nuget is the `AngularJS` package, which is a complete different version of `angular` (the first version).

`Angular` (named `angular`, not `angularJS`, published with a version >2.0.0 on npm as `@angular/...`) is not present on Nuget as a package, that's why you can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something prebuilt you will have to use `npm install -g @angular/cli` instead of Nuget. Angular cli quick start link 
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

If You want to install you can use `Install-Package Angular4 -Version 1.1.0`  and follow these steps:

````````````````````````````````````````````
Angular 4
*********

Prerequisites
`````````````
1. Download and Install Node js
2. Install Visual studio 2015 update 3 or above
3. Download and Install TypeScript 2.6.1 for Visual Studio 2015 (https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links)

Follow the steps to install package.
````````````````````````````````````
1. Create an new project with empty template and include dependencies for MVC and WebApi to the project
2. Install the package using command 'Install-Package Angular4 -Version 1.1.0'

Follow the steps after package installation
```````````````````````````````````````````
1. Open Node.js Command Prompt
2. Navigate to project location(use commands such as pushd,cd etc)
3. Run the command 'npm install'
````````````````````````````````````````````